# Multiple organisers in google calendar event API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, icalendar, google-developers-console

I am using the Google Calendar's event API. I have a unique requirements for creating a event is that for one particular event I need to make multiple organisers.

For example If there is an event E with attendees A1 and A2, then in A1's calendar he should be an organiser and  A2's calendar he should be shown as organiser.

I am not able to find out how can I do this with API. There is one website in the market is doing the same as  I mentioned but I could not able to find out how can I do this.

Could anyone please help me to find out this ??

Comment: Seeing as the Google calendar web application doesn't seam to have the ability to have more then one organizer set.   I dont think your going to get it to work with the api either.

Comment: The RFC5545 spec doesn't seem to allow for this either.  Compare ORGANIZER with ATTENDEE.  Organizer is "the organizer' whereas attendee is 'an attendee' and examples have multiple attendees. 
The spec does allow for a SENT-BY on behalf of the organizer.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.8.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From checking on the Google Calendar Web app it also appears that they do not allow more than one "Organizer" or "Owner" for the event so as DalmTo mentioned it might not be feasible either for the API. [https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308863?hl=en#:~:text=If%20you%20own%20an%20event,event%20in%20your%20calendar%20grid.&text=Change%20owner.,message%20if%20you%20need%20to](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308863?hl=en#:%7E:text=If%20you%20own%20an%20event,event%20in%20your%20calendar%20grid.&text=Change%20owner.,message%20if%20you%20need%20to).